# Excel cubevalue error #N/A FieldName with period

Tags: excel, powerpivot, cube

I have written the following expression with cubevalue

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Sum of Indicator Value]","[economics].[Ticker].&["&($B$21)&"]","[economics].[Indicator Name].[Avg. Diluted Shares Outstanding]","[economics].[date].&["&TEXT($A3,"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS")&"]")
```

Excel returns #N/A and I have filtered the error down until I have noticed it is due to the "period" in `[Avg. Diluted Shares Outstanding]`. I guess it is because Excel is understanding it as a Member_Expression separator instead of part of the Member_Expression name.

Does anybody know how I find the workaround? I think there should be an ampersand way of doing it but I have not been able to find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with a period in a field name.